# When using bower, can I keep the cloned repository I use a git endpoint for a package?

Tags: dependency-management, bower

I'm would like to be able to specify dependencies in my bower.json that not only are downloaded and copied to the packages folder, but actually making a clone of the respository and keep it there.

This is not unheard of: php's composer does exactly this in development

Why I need this, you might ask? Because I have a project with some internal (read: non-public) libraries as dependencies. Those libraries are meant to be used as part of another project. Think of them like rails gems. For example:

MyApp
  |--- libA
  |--- libB

Those libraries are also being developed, and it would be nice to keep the git repo so I can easily modify and submit patches when a bug is found when working on MyApp.

Anyone knows of any CLI or bowerrc option that can force this kind of behaviour?